# Paint jcomponent in 2 places

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm trying to draw scrolling icons and I'm stumped. All the code I have now is the icons sitting on a 5x5 static grid of JPanels (Custom paint method) with icons I drew in 5 seconds.

So I have the icons sitting on their own little component, say 50x50, on a grid, so a column looks like this:

icon 1

icon 2

icon 3

icon 4

I want to be able to drag them down and paint them in a loop so that if you drag down a little it is drawn like this:

bottom half of icon 4

icon 1

icon 2

icon 3

top half of icon 4

My question is simply how I would draw/split up the icon to draw it in halves (part at the bottom where it would go off screen, and the other part at the top. Since it's scrolling I want the split icon to be the same object if possible (just in 2 different places while it is off screen) so that when it is dragged down completely the order will have changed to:

icon 4

icon 1

icon 2

icon 3

and so on.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't have the same JPanel in two places, but you *can* have the same ImageIcon in two places, and that's what I'd do.

Comment: See also [roulette](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+roulette+example).